# How can we run connect-standalone with the same connector with two different configurations?

Tags: bash, apache-kafka, gnu-screen, apache-kafka-connect

I am using a sink connector with two different sinks(of the same type), the connector needs to be invoked with two different configuration. Currently, we are dealing with that using `screen`:

**launchScript.sh**

```
screen -dmS conn-one runConnector.sh config/connect-sink-conn-one.properties config/conn-one.properties
screen -dmS conn-two ./bin/runConnector.sh config/conn-two.properties config/conn-two.properties
```

**runConnector.sh**

```
connect-standalone $1 $2
```

Is there a way of achieving this without having to use GNU Screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bin/connect-standalone.sh` script can take multiple properties files with different connector configurations. You just have to use different names for each connector. So for example you can do something like this:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-sink.properties config/connect-file-sink2.properties
```

Where `config/connect-file-sink.properties` is:

```
name=local-file-sink
connector.class=FileStreamSink
tasks.max=1
file=test.sink.txt
topics=connect-test
```

and `config/connect-file-sink2.properties` is:

```
name=local-file-sink2
connector.class=FileStreamSink
tasks.max=1
file=test.sink.txt2
topics=connect-test
```

Answer (score 0):

`connect-standalone` already takes one or more connector property files in addition to one worker property files.

Or you can run `connect-distributed`, as its meant to be a long running service, then you POST as many JSON configs as you want to port 8083, by default